# Postgres error: LINE 2: FROM ods.academic_outcome_pu ^ SQL state: 42601 Character: 8

Tags: sql, postgresql

Trying to join two tables but am getting an error

```
SELECT 
  FROM ods.academic_outcome_pu 
 INNER JOIN ods.academic_outcome_pu 
    ON ods.academic_study.academic_period=ods.academic_outcome_pu.academic_period
   AND ON ods.academic_study.person_uid=ods.academic_outcome_pu.person_uid
   AND ON ods.academic_study.program=ods.academic_outcome_pu.program
```

Error returned:

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FROM"
> LINE 2: FROM ods.academic_outcome_pu 
> SQL state: 42601
> Character: 8
> ```

Comment: Normally you would be selecting *something*, although I think Postgres allows you select nothing at all.

Comment: @GordonLinoff for all supported versions, this is true. But for 9.3 and older, the select list is required. Thus this might be the error here. Anyways there are also other mistakes (namely the 2 ```ON```s after the ```AND```s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to join two tables, but repeated the same table in the `FROM-list`. From the aliases, it seems you have `ods.academic_study` and `ods.academic_outcome_pu` tables, and had better using aliases instead of explicitly writing the table names everytime to qualify the columns stated for the join conditions. And keyword `ON` should be used only once.

Btw, your error raises due to missing columns next to `SELECT` keyword. ( col[1/2] are just presumed column names which should be replaced by the real column names ) :

```
SELECT ods.col1, ods.col2, aop.col1, aop.col2
  FROM ods.academic_study ast 
  JOIN ods.academic_outcome_pu aop
    ON ast.academic_period = aop.academic_period
   AND ast.person_uid = aop.person_uid -- this first "AND" can be replaced by "WHERE" which could be used once also.
   AND ast.program = aop.program
```